# How to change input method of Django default form ? from text input to choices

Tags: django

I have below create view,

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','name']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and in Post create template I just put it as a form tag

```
<form method="POST" >
            {% csrf_token %}
      
                {{ form|crispy }}
            
        </form>
```

I want `name` field to be dropdown choice in frontend HTML, What shall I do ?

*It is possible by adding choice field in models.py but I can not do that and I have another idea to implement,*

Comment: Update code django form

Comment: it have no extra form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this in my opinion is to create a form class and pass the form to your view rather than having the view create the form.

Here is what a form could look like

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import Select
#also import your models from your app

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      # name_choices needs to be a list of tuples that have
      # the select option value as the first index, and the option display text
      # as the second
      name_choices = [(value,option_text),...]
      model = Post
      fields = ['title','name']
      widgets = {'name':Select(choices=name_choices)}
```